# declaring own datatypes with JDL

Tags: java, types, jhipster, jdl

I want to declare my own datatype in order to use it in an other entity.

JDL doesn't seem to recognize the entities that I already declared. How can I declare my own datatypes?

```py
entity Adress{
    street String,
    streetNumber Integer,
    postCode Integer,
    city String
}

entity Doctor {
    lanr Integer,
    telephone Integer,
    adress Adress
}
```

I expected to be able to use `Adress` as an `Datatype` because the JDL will create a Java `Class`.

Answer (score 2):

Jhipster currently doesn't support embedded "entities".

Found this https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6306

What happens if you use a relationship to solve it?

```
relationship OneToMany {
        Doctor{address} to Address
    }
```

https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/